# If $x^2+y^2+xy=1$ then find minimum of $x^3y+xy^3+4$

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives, maxima-minima

> If $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$ and $x^2+y^2+xy=1$ then find the minimum value of $x^3y+xy^3+4$

**My Attempt:**

$x^3y+xy^3+4$

$\Rightarrow xy(x^2+y^2)+4$

$\Rightarrow xy(1-xy)+4$ (from first equation)

$\Rightarrow xy-(xy)^2+4  =f(x)$

For minimum value, $\frac{df(x)}{dx}=0$.

$\Rightarrow \frac{df(x)}{dx}=(y-2xy²) + \frac{dy}{dx}(x-2yx²)=0$

How should I proceed from here?

Comment: Have you tried using Lagrange multipliers?

Comment: You should take the function $f(x,y)$ and set its partial derivatives to 0.

Comment: Are you sure not "maximum"?

Comment: @Marc Dinh it does make differentiation easier but it gives same result as what I did- $y=1/2x$. On substituting this in $f(x)$ to get a function solely in $x$ then minimizing that we get unreal values of $x$

Comment: @VIVID yes, I am sure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By AM-GM, $x^2+y^2=|x|^2+|y|^2\ge2|xy|$ so $r^2=x^2+y^2$ has extrema $\tfrac23,\,2$ respectively achieved by$$2xy=x^2+y^2\implies1=(1+1/2)(x^2+y^2)$$and$$-2xy=x^2+y^2\implies1=(1-1/2)(x^2+y^2).$$Note the minimum of $r^2(1-r^2)$ on $[\tfrac23,\,2]$ occurs at $r^2=2$. In particular, $x=-y=1$ minimizes $r^2(1-r^2)+4$ as $2\times-1+4=2$.

Comment: Can you please write your answer in a little more detail I am finding it a bit hard to follow along with what you did

Comment: @l1mbo See edit.

Comment: understood now, thanks!